# Is it dangerous to use synchronize in a non-VCL application?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

If Delphi code was written with synchronize to serialize access to the main VCL thread, but this code then is used in a non-VCL application, will it synchronize with the main thread of the application or just have no effect at all?

---

Example:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin

  // ... other code

  Synchronize(SomeMethod);

  // ...

end;
```

Let's assume

- it is a non-VCL application which has a main thread which executes in an endless loop (or until terminated)
- the main thread does not call [`CheckSynchronize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.CheckSynchronize) directly or in a WakeMainThread handler
- a secondary thread runs and executes Synchronize(SomeMethod) like in the example above

Will the thread hang on the Synchronize(SomeMethod) line?

Comment: Is the non-VCL application in your control? If not then you can't use `Synchronize`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can imagine a `synchronize(CallEventHandler)` in a library where I can assign a method to the event handler. The compiler will not complain if it is a non-VCL application.

Comment: Of course the compiler won't complain. It has nothing to do with the syntax of the command or the scope of the identifiers. But @David is wrong that you can't use `Synchronize`. You can use it all you want. You just have to publicize that you're using it so that the consumer of your library knows to use `CheckSynchronize`. I don't know what happens if the host doesn't honor its part of the contract, though. Feel free to write a test program and report your own results here.

Comment: @Rob If the app is not in your control then how is it going to call CheckSynchronize? I think we are in accord here.

Comment: Easy, @David. You put a note in the readme or the usage synopsis: "This library uses feature X. Therefore, consumers of this library need to do Y; VCL programs do it automatically." And in the FAQ: "Q: Why does the library hang when `EventHandler` is assigned? A: You have a non-VCL program and you have neglected to do Y."

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "assign a WakeMainThread method to set CheckSynchronize." CheckSynchronize is not something you can "set," and it has nothing to do with whether WakeMainThread is assigned.

Comment: @Rob If the code is a plugin, for example, then that would not be viable.

Comment: `WakeMainThread` isn't required. The main thread could simply call `CheckSynchronize` of its own accord, without being told to.

Answer (score 9):

`TThread` provides facilities for non-VCL programs to check the synchronization queue, so they can continue to use multithreaded libraries that expect to synchronize their methods. This is described in the [documentation for `CheckSynchronize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.CheckSynchronize). Remember that it's the application's job to check the queue, not your library's.

As long as the application honors its part of the contract, your use of `Synchronize` should be fine. If it doesn't, though, then your program will not work correctly, but I don't know what exact symptoms to expect. Hanging certainly sounds plausible.

Comment: see my edit: the DocWiki is a bit unclear, it reads as if assigning WakeMainThread and calling CheckSynchronize is an optional optimization.

Comment: Assigning `WakeMainThread` is the optimization. It's expected that the main thread would wake itself *eventually* and notice the new synchronized tasks to perform, but `WakeMainThread`, if provided, tells the main thread to wake up *immediately*. It cuts down on latency.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my previous comment! I have read in your comment `I don't know what happens if the host doesn't honor its part of the contract, though. ` and then deleted it assuming it is not so easy to answer

Comment: That detail isn't easy *for me* to answer because I don't have Delphi installed anywhere to test it. You do.

Comment: The background thread blocks until CheckSynchronize has been called. What else could happen?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it dangerous to use synchronize in a non-VCL application?

Yes it is dangerous. If your main thread is not calling `CheckSynchronize` then `Synchronize` will result in deadlock.

> Let's assume
>
> - it is a non-VCL application which has a main thread which executes in an endless loop (or until terminated)
> - the main thread does not call `CheckSynchronize` directly or in a `WakeMainThread` handler
> - a secondary thread runs and executes `Synchronize(SomeMethod)` like in the example above
>
> Will the thread hang on the `Synchronize(SomeMethod)` line?

The call to `Synchronize` will block the background thread until the main thread calls `CheckSynchronize`. So, if the main thread never calls `CheckSynchronize`, the background thread will block indefinitely.

The following program illustrates this:

```
program TheBigSleep;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Windows;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(SysUtils.Beep);
end;

begin
  with TMyThread.Create do
    WaitForSingleObject(Handle, INFINITE);
    //don't call WaitFor since that, in turn, calls CheckSynchronize
end.
```

Comment: +1, and about `Synchronize`, don't ever use it. The thread should not be dependant of what is outside of it's scope. Better to use non-blocking calls like `PostMessage` or `TThread.Queue`. See [mghie's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/30568/mghie) answer to [Is it better to use TThread's “Synchronize” or use Window Messages for IPC between main and child thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1806947/576719) for a summary.

Comment: `TThread.Queue()` uses the same queue as `TThread.Synchronize()`, and so has the same requirement that the main thread needs to call `CheckSynchronize()` periodically to process the requests from either function.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are putting the Delphi code in a library for other apps to use, I would not advise using `Synchronize()` at all, since your thread has no concept of what is going on outside of itself.  A better choice is to have the thread expose a callback event that the thread can call in its own context when needed, and then let the app provide a callback function handler that decides the best way to synchronize with the app's main thread as needed.