# Synchronize, CheckSynchronize and WaitFor in Apache Web Application DLL

Tags: apache, delphi

Considering the following SO Question:
[Is it dangerous to use synchronize in a non-VCL application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689159/is-it-dangerous-to-use-synchronize-in-a-non-vcl-application)

I was wondering how `TThread's Synchronize`, `CheckSynchronize` and `WaitFor` is affected when using them inside an Apache Web Application DLL.

I started investigating this when I realized `WaitFor` was locking/hanging. Inside `WaitFor` it checks `if CurrentThread.ThreadID = MainThreadID` and then repeats checking the result of `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` and based on the result it will do `CheckSynchronize` or `PeekMessage` and when it received a `WAIT_OBJECT_0` it will finally exit the loop. If the `MainThreadID` is not the same as the `CurrentThreadID`, then `WaitFor` will do a single `WaitForSingleObject`.

So I created the following test Apache Web Module DLL to see what the `MainThreadID` is during the lifetime of a web request.

```
type
  TTheThread = class(TThread)
  private
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
  end;

  TWebModule1 = class(TWebModule)
    procedure WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
      Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure WebModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WebModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

procedure DoLog(AMsg : String);

var
  WebModuleClass: TComponentClass = TWebModule1;
  TestThread : TTheThread;
  Logger : TLogger;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}

{$R *.dfm}

procedure DoLog(AMsg : String);
begin
  AMsg := AMsg + #13#10 + 'MainThreadID: ' + InttoStr(MainThreadID) +
                 #13#10 + 'CurrThreadID: ' + InttoStr(GetCurrentThreadId);

  Logger.Log(ltNormal,AMsg);
end;

procedure TTheThread.Execute;
begin
  While not Terminated do
    begin
      Sleep(5000);
      DoLog('Thread Execute - Inside While - Terminated: ' + BoolToStr(Terminated,True));
    end;

  DoLog('Thread Execute - End - Terminated: ' + BoolToStr(Terminated,True));
end;


procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Response.Content :=
    '<html>' +
    '<head><title>Web Server Application</title></head>' +
    '<body>Web Server Application</body>' +
    '</html>';

  DoLog('WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction');
end;

procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Logger := TLogger.Create(nil);
  {set some Logger properties}

  DoLog('WebModuleCreate - Before Thread Create');

  TestThread := TTheThread.Create(True);
  TestThread.Start;

  DoLog('WebModuleCreate - Created Thread');
end;

procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoLog('WebModuleDestroy Before Terminate');

  TestThread.Terminate;

  DoLog('WebModuleDestroy Before WaitFor');

  TestThread.WaitFor;

  DoLog('WebModuleDestroy Before Free');

  TestThread.Free;

  DoLog('WebModuleDestroy End');

  Logger.Free;
end;

end.
```

So I start Apache, go to the web page in a browser, count down about 12 seconds and then I stop Apache. I give it a while but the `httpd` service only destroys a few threads but then stays the same and never closes.

Here is the log:

```
2021-03-03 10:23:42 081  WebModuleCreate - Before Thread Create
2021-03-03 10:23:42 081    ^ MainThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:23:42 081    ^ CurrThreadID: 6328
2021-03-03 10:23:42 081  WebModuleCreate - Created Thread
2021-03-03 10:23:42 081    ^ MainThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:23:42 081    ^ CurrThreadID: 6328
2021-03-03 10:23:42 081  WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction
2021-03-03 10:23:42 081    ^ MainThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:23:42 081    ^ CurrThreadID: 6328
2021-03-03 10:23:47 093  Thread Execute - Inside While - Terminated: False
2021-03-03 10:23:47 093    ^ MainThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:23:47 093    ^ CurrThreadID: 2220
2021-03-03 10:23:52 100  Thread Execute - Inside While - Terminated: False
2021-03-03 10:23:52 100    ^ MainThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:23:52 100    ^ CurrThreadID: 2220
2021-03-03 10:23:57 101  Thread Execute - Inside While - Terminated: False
2021-03-03 10:23:57 101    ^ MainThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:23:57 101    ^ CurrThreadID: 2220
2021-03-03 10:23:58 313  WebModuleDestroy Before Terminate
2021-03-03 10:23:58 313    ^ MainThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:23:58 313    ^ CurrThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:23:58 313  WebModuleDestroy Before WaitFor
2021-03-03 10:23:58 313    ^ MainThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:23:58 313    ^ CurrThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:24:02 108  Thread Execute - Inside While - Terminated: True
2021-03-03 10:24:02 108    ^ MainThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:24:02 108    ^ CurrThreadID: 2220
2021-03-03 10:24:02 108  Thread Execute - End - Terminated: True
2021-03-03 10:24:02 108    ^ MainThreadID: 2432
2021-03-03 10:24:02 108    ^ CurrThreadID: 2220
```

As you can see, `WaitFor` never finishes. Interesting that `OnWebModuleCreate` runs in a different thread than the assumed `MainThreadID` but `OnWebModuleDestroy` runs in the same `MainThreadID` and as such `CurrentThreadID = MainThreadID` when `WaitFor` is called.

So I suspect I will have to never use `Synchronize`, and `WaitFor` in this case. Is that correct or are there more to this than I see?

What do I use to do synchronization if by my assumption the so-called main thread may not be calling `CheckSynchronize` at all and can I just do a single `WaitForSingleObject` instead of `WaitFor`? I suspect synchronization as in the sense to a main thread might never be required here at all.

### Update

After a lot of reading I came across the information about `DLLMain/DLLProc` and that it is called whenever a process is "attached/detached" and a thread is "attached/detached"

- [DllMain entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain)
- [Dynamic-Link Library Entry-Point
  Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-entry-point-function)

There is also a blog post by Raymond Chen that [discusses thread deadlocks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283) in `DLLMain`.

So it seems that because `DLLMain` is called when the the DLL is unloaded and also when a thread exits I cannot do a thread `WaitFor` in the DLL Unloading code (`OnWebModuleDestroy`) as that will obviously cause a deadlock as the one will be waiting for the other. I'll appreciate it if anyone can advise on this opinion.

Comment: I don’t have experience with Apache Webapplications, but if these behave the same as ISAPI dll on IIS, then you need to terminate the thread in the Termination callback routine `TerminateExtension`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap:

A DLL's `DLLMain/DLLProc` is called whenever a process is "attached/detached" and a thread is "attached/detached"

- [DllMain entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain)
- [Dynamic-Link Library Entry-Point
  Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-entry-point-function)

There is also a blog post by Raymond Chen that [discusses thread deadlocks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283) in `DLLMain`.

Because `DLLMain` is called when the the DLL is unloaded and also when a thread exits I cannot do a thread `WaitFor` in the DLL Unloading code (`OnWebModuleDestroy`) as that will obviously cause a deadlock as the one will be waiting for the other.

After R.Hoek's comment I started looking to see if Apache calls some sort of cleanup procedure before it actually unloads the module DLL and came upon its `apr_pool_cleanup` and the companion `apr_pool_cleanup_register` procedure which registers a hook into the the cleanup. Fortunately this has already been handled inside the `Web.ApacheApp` unit and its `TApacheApplication` class that has an `OnTerminate` "event" which is called by the `apr_pool_cleanup`.

Assigning cleanup code to the `OnTerminate` "event" allows you to properly get rid of your threads without fear of deadlocks in `DLLMain`:

```
TApacheApplication(Application).OnTerminate := OnApplicationTerminate;
```